# Chart.js - barchart - plugin labels

Tags: plugins, label, chart.js

I need your advice and need your assistance.
I'm using Chart.js and installed the labels plugin ( https://github.com/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels).

I want to show the percentage of each Label on top of the bar like in the image below - in my chart summarised as Weeks . How can I define the max value (which is set correct for label 1 = week1) for every week? So each Week would sum up to 100% (like in Week1)

Is there a way?

Here is my code below

Sorry for my bad English, and thank you very much for your kindness and help

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myBarChart");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["WEEK1", "WEEK2", "WEEK3", "WEEK4", "WEEK5"
    ],
    datasets: [{
      label: "AMPDS ",
      backgroundColor: "#dc3545",
      borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      data: [20,24,30,36,10
      ],
    },
    {
      label: "VISITE",
      backgroundColor: "#ffc107",
      borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      data: [5,5,1,6,5
      ],
    },
    {
      label: "ABSTRICH",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      data: [10,12,15,18,20
    
      ],
    }
    
    ],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        time: {
          unit: 'month'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 6
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
    
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 55,
          maxTicksLimit: 5
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: true
        }
      }],
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    plugins: {
                    labels: {
            render: function (args) {  
    let max = 35; //This is the default 100% that will be used if no Max value is found
    
    return Math.round(args.value * 100 / max); //Calculate percent
  }
                    }
                }
            }
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum each week by accessing datasets by context and then use reduce function. Datalabel position can be set by **Chart.defaults.global.plugins.datalabels** before you create the chart. Using anchor end, align end will put the label on top of the bar.

```
    Chart.defaults.global.plugins.datalabels.anchor = 'end';
    Chart.defaults.global.plugins.datalabels.align = 'end';

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myBarChart");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["WEEK1", "WEEK2", "WEEK3", "WEEK4", "WEEK5"
            ],
            datasets: [{
            label: "AMPDS ",
            backgroundColor: "#dc3545",
            borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            data: [20,24,30,36,10
            ],
            },
            {
            label: "VISITE",
            backgroundColor: "#ffc107",
            borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            data: [5,5,1,6,5
            ],
            },
            {
            label: "ABSTRICH",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            data: [10,12,15,18,20
            
            ],
            }
            
            ],
        },
        options: {
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    formatter: (value, ctx) => {
                        const { dataIndex } = ctx
                        let datasets = ctx.chart.data.datasets
                        let max = datasets.reduce((a,c)=>a+c.data[dataIndex],0)
                        return Math.round(value * 100 / max);;
                    },
                }
            },
            scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                time: {
                unit: 'month'
                },
                gridLines: {
                display: false
                },
                ticks: {
                maxTicksLimit: 6
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 55,
                    maxTicksLimit: 5
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                    display: true
                    }
                }],
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    });
```